# Отключение скрипта при определенной ширине экрана

Tags: javascript

Такая проблема, как сделать, чтобы скрипт не работал, когда посетитель заходит с телефона (например ширина его дисплея >767)?

Данный метод не помогает:

```
<script>
If (document.body.clientWidth>767){
  document.write('<script src="javascript.js">')
}
</script></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<script>
if (document.body.clientWidth>800){
   document.write("<script>console.log('hello!');<\/script>");
}  
</script>
```

Вот так работает. Если ширина экрана маленькая, то алерта нет. Если более 800 пикселей - алерт появляется. Надо экранировать слеш `<\/script>`. Если его не экранировать, то не работает - браузер подумает, что скрипт - это кусок кода:

```js
<script>
if (document.body.clientWidth>800){
   document.write("<script>console.log('hello!');<\/script>
```

Идея того, что скрипт отрабатывает при одной ширине экрана и не работает при другой - интересная.

Насчет availWidth - это ширина экрана *вообще* в пикселях. она не меняется никогда, если монитор не менять. можно использовать innerWidth и clientWidth. вот их описание. https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

Comment: <script>
if (document.body.clientWidth>800){
   document.write("<script src="javascript.js"><\/script>");
}  
</script> ////////////// Всё равно не работает.

Comment: у тебя написано "<script src="javascript.js"><\/script>". интерпретатор думает, что надо вставить кусок "<script src=" .думаю, что не работает из-за того, что надо кавычки использовать РАЗНЫЕ - "<script src='javascript.js'><\/script>"

Comment: я не знаю, только у меня так, или это не правильно, но всё равно скрипт не отключается..

Comment: попробуй включить скрипт не из внешнего файла, а прямо в элемент скрипт. посмотри, что будет. поставь точки останова в скрипт и запусти код. это надо дебажить и смотреть, что консоль пишет

Comment: ты умеешь пользоваться точками останова (дл нахождения ошибок) браузерных инструментов разработчика?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется используют

```
window.screen.availWidth
```